# How to pass a typedef function as a parameter in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I've been looking around online for awhile and I haven't found anything exactly like my issue. I am using a class that has this thing defined:

```
typedef bool ProgressCallback(double progress);
```

There is then a function that uses this like so:

```
// The documentation says that it will call progress_callback()
// during the write where the progress parameter = percentage complete
void WriteToFile(char* filename, ProgressCallback* progress_callback)
```

How exactly am I supposed to call this function?? It's mainly the typedef syntax that's throwing me off, because it's not usually this difficult to pass a function as a parameter. Here's what I tried though:

```
// Apparently I can't just say "Progress Callback MyCallback{}"
// Since it gives me "function type may not come from a typedef" error
bool MyCallbackFunction(double progress){
    return true;
}

void OtherFunction(){

    // Can't assign. I get "a value type of bool (*)(double progress)" cannot be
    // used to initalize an entity of type ProgressCallback*" error.
    ProgressCallback* myfunction = MyCallbackFunction;
    WriteToFile("Test.txt", myfunction);
}
```

Obviously I know I am doing this incorrectly. But this is the closest I've gotten. I have absolutely no idea how I am supposed to pass that argument into WriteToFile().

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: C doesn't have classes.

Comment: A typedef just declares an identifier as an alias for a type.  In this case, that type is a particular function type, and you are passing a pointer to a function of that type.  You can call the pointed-to function by dereferencing the the pointer to get a function designator, and forming a function call expression with it: `(*progress_callback)(0.5)`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfb3cb3a017f5269). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are making something up. Your initialization cannot and does not generate "cannot be used to initalize" error. Don't post fake code. Post real code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: The code you posted here works fine (apart from the `CallBack` vs. `Callback` typo and string literals being `const char []`, so `WriteToFile` should be declared as taking a `const char *`).

Comment: My example is in C++, yes. But I never used any classes in my example. The library is compatible with C as well.

Comment: You said "*I am using a class that has this thing defined*".

Comment: If this is supposed to be C, then `bool` is undeclared.

Comment: That was my fault then. I'm not using any classes, I meant I am using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I needed to explicitly declare a calling convention to do this. So I changed:

```
bool MyCallbackFunction(double progress){
    return true;
}
```

to

```
bool __stdcall MyCallbackFunction(double progress){
    return true;
}
```

and it seems to accept it now.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
typedef bool (*ProgressCallback)(double progress);
```

to define `ProgressCallback`.

Then, you can use

```
ProgressCallback myfunction = MyCallbackFunction;
WriteToFile("Test.txt", myfunction);
```

Comment: I'd like to do that, but it's not my library to modify so I'm sort of stuck with what they gave me.